# Why is the variable automatically going to 255 when I try to add it by 1?

Tags: python

So I have a variable set to go up by "1" in a pygame loop, for a fade effect. For some reason, it's going to 255 when I want to go up by 1 at a time. Here's what I have:

```
while alph <= 255:
    alph += 1
```

Comment: because this loop will stop at 255 so your alph will acquire 255 value and then it will stop

Comment: If that's _all_ you have, how do you know that it _isn't_ going through all the other steps? There's no output shown so you just don't see them; all 255 iterations happen before the loop has exited even once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, if you're working with a game, there's already a looping function built into pygame, where each time it finishes a loop that's a completed frame. Thus, during a single pygame loop (single frame) it encounters the code you've written here, and must update `alph` from 0 to 256 all in one frame before it can exit your loop and refresh/rerender your UI

Comment: why would it stop at 255 though? his loop condition is `<= 255` so shouldn't the loop continue at alph = 255?

Comment: Run through the loop in your mind... 253 + 1 goes to 254. Then we check the loop condition again. Then what?

Comment: Ah, you're right, I didn't catch that it was <= instead of <. The loop would exit at 256. I'll update my answer to be more accurate. Good catch